# Getting data from 2 tables when they dont have any primary-foregin key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which are data sources say A,B. I want to fetch data for 4 columns from these tables. The 4 columns are present in the both the tables. 'A' table may or may not have values for the one or all the 4 columns. But for sure B table has values for all of them. So if it is present in A i have to select from them or else i have select from B. Say Col1, Col2 are present in A and col3 and col4 are not in A table, then it should fetch col1, col2 from A and col 3, col4 from B table.

I am not good in SQL. Can someone help me with this? Hope my question is clear. If not please let me know

Comment: As you say, if something in table a is missing, you have to take table b's column. So how should you know, which row of table b you have to take? There should be a column(or more in combination) that make a row unique, or at least relatable with a row in the other table.

Comment: they have to fetch for a common id which is unique in both the tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to find a matching in A if it exists.  If a matching row does not exist, the row from B will still remain in the query.  In cases where A has a NULL value for one of the columns, COALESCE() can be used to fall back on B's value for that column.

I wasn't clear from your question on which criteria you would like to use to match rows between A and B, but maybe a query like the following will help if you fill in that detail.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.col1,B.col1)
        , COALESCE(A.col2,B.col2)
        , COALESCE(A.col3,B.col3)
        , COALESCE(A.col4,B.col4)
FROM B
LEFT OUTER JOIN A
    ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: I may be wrong but if you are using join shouldnt they be related via primary key foriegn key?

Comment: It is very common that you would have such a relationship when using a join, but it is not required by SQL Server.  However, you may want to exercise caution in making sure that the join does not match more rows than intended if there is some specific reason that you can't have the FK relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can do joins without a relationship between tables. The example below shows what i think you are aiming for.

```
DECLARE @tableone TABLE(id int,FirstName varchar(50),Secondname varchar(50))
insert into @tableone values(1,null, null);
insert into @tableone values(2,null, 'Dev');
insert into @tableone values(3,'Arjun', null);
insert into @tableone values(4,'Jack', 'Bilalo');

DECLARE @tabletwo TABLE(id int,FirstName varchar(50),Secondname varchar(50))
insert into @tabletwo values(1,'John', 'cena');
insert into @tabletwo values(2,'Michel', 'Dev');
insert into @tabletwo values(3,'Arjun', 'Ramn');
insert into @tabletwo values(4,'Jack', 'Bilalo');

SELECT A.Id, COALESCE(A.FirstName,B.FirstName) As Firstname, COALESCE(A.Secondname,B.Secondname) As Secondname
FROM @tableone A
    JOIN @tabletwo B
        ON A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 0):

[Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbcfe/1)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbcfe/1

**Sample code**

```
create table tableone(id int,FirstName varchar(50),Secondname varchar(50))
insert into tableone values(1,'John', 'cena');
insert into tableone values(2,'Michel', 'Dev');
insert into tableone values(3,'Arjun', 'Ramn');
insert into tableone values(4,'Jack', 'Bilalo');

create table tabletwo(id_tb1 int,"address" varchar(150))
insert into tabletwo values('1','Uk');
insert into tabletwo values('2','USA');
insert into tabletwo values('3','China');
insert into tabletwo values('4','India');

select a.FirstName,a.SecondName,b.address as location 
from tableone a inner join tabletwo b
on a.id=b.id_tb1
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: i don think innerjoin will help here as it requires relationship between the 2 source tables